# ng-repeat not working with nested json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following json object

```
$scope.receipts = {
    acquirer : [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "REDE",
            balanceAmount: 4462.29,
            cardProducts: [
                {
                    cardProduct: {
                        balanceAmount: 2222,
                        id: 1,
                        name: "MASTERCARD CREDITO",
                        lancamentos: [ 
                            {
                                description: "vendas",
                                payedAmount: 1111   
                            },
                            {
                                description: "cancelamentos",
                                payedAmount: 1111
                            },
                            {
                                description: "ajustes",
                                payedAmount: 1111
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I am trying to make an nested table using angular ng-repeat

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts[0]">
            <tr class="group">
                <th></th>
                <th>lançamento</th>
                <th>valor líquido (R$)</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th class="except"></th>

                <th>
                    <div class="cardFlag brand_{{i.id}}"></div>
                    {{ i.name }} {{ i.lancamentos[0].teste.description }}
                </th>
                <th>{{i.balanceAmount | currency}}</th>
                <th><a href="#/receipts/details">detalhes</a></th>
            </tr>
            <ng-repeat ng-repeat="e in i.lancamentos[0]">
                <tr class="inset">
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="inset-1">{{ e.description }}</th>
                    <th>{{e.payedAmount}} </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </ng-repeat>
        </tbody>
```

My first `ng-repeat` is working very well. My problem actually is on my 2nd `ng-repeat`, which doesn't output anything.

What would be a better approach to handle this kind of nested json and make `ng-repeat` works on "**lancamentos**" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you dont have an id property inside lancamentos[], change your foreach to

```
ng-repeat="e in i.lancamentos track by $index"
```

Comment: @vbotio - Glad I helped. Please mark as answer of this helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that ng-repeat go on the tr?  And don't say `i.lancamentos[0]` since that's going to just be the first one.

```
<tr class="inset" ng-repeat="e in i.lancamentos[0]">
    <th></th>
    <th class="inset-1">{{ e.description }}</th>
    <th>{{e.payedAmount}} </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this object:

```
{
    acquirer : [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "REDE",
            balanceAmount: 4462.29,
            cardProducts: [
                {
                    cardProduct: {
                        balanceAmount: 2222,
                        id: 1,
                        name: "MASTERCARD CREDITO",
                        lancamentos: [ 
                            {
                                description: "vendas",
                                payedAmount: 1111   
                            },
                            {
                                description: "cancelamentos",
                                payedAmount: 1111
                            },
                            {
                                description: "ajustes",
                                payedAmount: 1111
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

This block:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts[0]">
```

will alias i to this object:

```
{
    cardProduct: {
        balanceAmount: 2222,
        id: 1,
        name: "MASTERCARD CREDITO",
        lancamentos: [
            {
                description: "vendas",
                payedAmount: 1111   
            },
            {
                description: "cancelamentos",
                payedAmount: 1111
            },
            {
                description: "ajustes",
                payedAmount: 1111
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which means this block:

```
<ng-repeat ng-repeat="e in i.lancamentos[0]">
```

actually needs to be:

```
<ng-repeat ng-repeat="e in i.cardProduct.lancamentos">
```

Edit: As observed in some of the other comments, assuming there may be more than one element in the acquirer.cardProducts array, you'll want to modify your first ng-repeat by removing the [0].

```
<tbody ng-repeat="i in receipts.acquirer[0].cardProducts">
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
<ng-repeat ng-repeat="e in i.lancamentos[0]">
   <tr class="inset">
      <th></th>
      <th class="inset-1">{{ e.description }}</th>
      <th>{{e.payedAmount}} </th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
</ng-repeat>
```

Into this:

```
<tr class="inset" ng-repeat="e in i.lancamentos">
   <th></th>
   <th class="inset-1">{{ e.description }}</th>
   <th>{{e.payedAmount}} </th>
   <th></th>
</tr>
```